# Php/MySQL if statement that returns information based on value selected

Tags: php, mysql

[page1.php]

```
<form action="result.php" method="POST" style='color:white;font-family: __custom;'>
    <input type="text" placeholder="Search.." name="search" /><br><br>
    <center>
        <select name="example">
        <option value="A">A</option>
        <option value="B">B</option>
        <option value="C">C</option>
        </select>
        <br><br>
    </center>
    &nbsp;<input type="submit" value="GO!" id="sub"/>
</form><br><br><br>
```

[result.php]

```
<?php
$searchq = $_POST['search'] // search textbox;
//Connect to mySQL and retrieve all contacts
$conErr = "Error connecting to server or database";
$con = mysqli_connect("host", "user", "password", "database");
// Check connection
if (mysqli_connect_errno()) {
    echo $connErr;
}
if ($_POST['example'] == 'C') {
    echo "You chose inCludes";
    $result = mysqli_query($con, "SELECT * FROM people WHERE name LIKE '%$searchq%' ORDER BY name ASC");
    while ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result)) {
        echo "<hr>";
        echo "All information regarding Select Statement";
        echo "<br>";
    }
} else if ($_POST['example'] == 'A') {
    echo "You chose EndsWith";
    $result = mysqli_query($con, "SELECT * FROM people WHERE name LIKE '$searchq%' ORDER BY name ASC");
    while ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result)) {
        echo "<hr>";
        echo "All information based on Select Statement";
        echo "<br>";
    }
} else {
    echo "Blah";
}
mysqli_close($con);
?>
</div>
```

What i'm trying to do is on page1.php the user searches for a keyword the chooses either A, B, or C from a dropdown. Based on the A, B, C the user goes to result.php and then the information is given based on the query.

The code above does not seem to be working [I do not get any results at all] [blank]. Please help.

Comment: Please explain 'does not seem to be working' - do you get an error message, what do you get?

Comment: Add error checking to your `mysqli_query()` calls.

Comment: Your query that says `EndsWith` actually searches for `BeginsWith`.

Comment: @Barmar or die(mysqli_error); do you mean that?

Comment: Okay thank you I guess that was the problem. @Barmar

Comment: This looks terrifyingly insecure. Are you **sure** your user parameters are [properly escaped](http://bobby-tables.com/php)? When using `mysqli` you should be using parameterized queries and [`bind_param`](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli-stmt.bind-param.php) to add user data to your query. **DO NOT** use string interpolation to accomplish this because you will create severe [SQL injection bugs](http://bobby-tables.com/).

Comment: @tadman should i use mysql_escape_string?

Comment: You should never use `mysql_real_escape_string` unless you're using `mysql_query`, and you shouldn't be using that in the first place. It's incompatible with `mysqli`. Just be disciplined about using placeholders to insert data and you'll be in much better shape.

Comment: @tadman I used placeholder for the search box can i use it with the combo box as well?

Comment: Anywhere you have user data you can use it, with the exception of column and table names. For those you should absolutely not be using user-data directly without some serious checking.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to search for something that ends with a string, you have to put the `%` wildcard at the beginning:

```
} else if ($_POST['example'] == 'A') {
    echo "You chose EndsWith";
    $result = mysqli_query($con, "SELECT * FROM people WHERE name LIKE '%$searchq' ORDER BY name ASC");
    while ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result)) {
        echo "<hr>";
        echo "All information based on Select Statement";
        echo "<br>";
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You missed the % wildcard after LIKE clause

```
else if ($_POST['example'] == 'A') {
echo "You chose EndsWith";
$result = mysqli_query($con, "SELECT * FROM people WHERE name LIKE '%$searchq%' ORDER BY name ASC");
while ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result)) {
    echo "<hr>";
    echo "All information based on Select Statement";
    echo "<br>";
}
}
```